# How do I access "System Settings" in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04

I keep seeing instructions that suggest I go to "System Settings". I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Which desktop / window manager are you running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System Settings if present by default as a shortcut in Ubuntu taskbar :

[image: system settings]

---

If you don't have this shortcut you can open it by doing :

**Command line way :**

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type :

```
unity-control-center
```

**Graphical way :**

Open Unity dash (click on the Ubuntu logo on the taskbar or use the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> key of your keyboard) and search for "**System Settings**" :

[image: dash system setting]

Comment: I'm not sure what the taskbar is but I don't see a Ubuntu logo. I used your keyboard suggestion but don't see "System Settings".  unity-control-center was not installed. I'm installing it now.

Comment: The taskbar is the bar on the left of your screen with all the icons. Do my pictures seem similar to your screen ?

Comment: OK. Installing  "unity-control-center" worked. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness, on a more up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04+, it's `gnome-control-center`.

Answer (score 10):

Click the wheel in the top right corner of the panel and then select <kbd>System Settings</kbd>.

[image: img]

Comment: I don't have a wheel in the top right corner.

Comment: You're probably running a different GUI environment than Unity.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Unity Sidebar]

Systems Settings is there as default short-cut in the Unity sidebar. If you hold down your "Windows" key, the sidebar should pop up. Keep it pushed and each icon will come up with a number on top of it. Press the number over "System Settings".

Hope this helps!